# Room Database Table is still empty after inserting new data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I've just finished [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#4) for my app.

But my problem is that even after I insert the data, my database is still empty. I checked that by viewing it in a Database browser and there are no records in it. Any help would be highly appreciated. If you need any more info let me know.

Dao object class:

```java
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertRecord(LocationDetails Details);
```

my entity class:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "location")
public class LocationDetails {

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String jsonObjectString;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String locationType;

    public String getLocationType() {
        return locationType;
    }

    public void setLocationType(String locationType) {
        this.locationType = locationType;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getJsonObjectString() {
        return jsonObjectString;
    }

    public void setJsonObjectString(String jsonObjectString) {
        this.jsonObjectString = jsonObjectString;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Lat: " + latitude + ", Long: " + longitude;
    }
}
```

This is my database controller class which my ViewModels use to interact with the DB.

```java
public class DatabaseController {

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private static DatabaseController sInstance;
    private LiveData<List<LocationDetails>> mListOfLocations;
    private Database mDatabase;

    private DatabaseController(Context context) {
        mDatabase = Database.getDatabase(context);
    }

    public static DatabaseController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    public static void initInstance(Context context) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseController(context);
    }

    public void addLocationRecord(LocationDetails locationDetails) {
        new insertAsyncTask(mDatabase).execute(locationDetails);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location Record Added Successfully");
    }

    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<LocationDetails, Void, Void> {

        private Database database;

        insertAsyncTask(Database database) {
            this.database = database;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(LocationDetails... databases) {
            database.mMyDao().insertRecord(databases[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added breakpoints at every step and checked. The entire code runs without any exception or error but still there is no record added in my Database.

And the question answered here is the same but his solution was different so not a duplicate.
[Room Database Table is still empty after inserting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726829/room-database-table-is-still-empty-after-inserting-data)

I receive these logs the first time:

```
2018-10-26 18:18:41.329 27827-27827/genesis.com.getlocation D/DatabaseController: Location Record Added Successfully
2018-10-26 18:18:41.345 27827-27876/genesis.com.getlocation D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x990a1f00,api=1)
2018-10-26 18:18:41.346 27827-27944/genesis.com.getlocation W/SQLiteConnection: Could not change the database journal as DB was busy. Proceeding...
2018-10-26 18:18:41.347 27827-27876/genesis.com.getlocation D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xaaf92040) (w:848 h:1264 s:848 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2018-10-26 18:18:41.347 27827-27876/genesis.com.getlocation D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xaaf92400) (w:848 h:1264 s:848 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2018-10-26 18:18:41.347 27827-27876/genesis.com.getlocation D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xaaf924c0) (w:848 h:1264 s:848 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2018-10-26 18:18:41.347 27827-27876/genesis.com.getlocation D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x990a1f00,api=1)
2018-10-26 18:18:41.362 27827-27944/genesis.com.getlocation W/SQLiteConnection: Could not change the database journal as DB was busy. Proceeding...
2018-10-26 18:18:41.369 27827-27944/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:41.372 27827-27944/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:41.374 27827-27827/genesis.com.getlocation D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: DecorView@74e9112[], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@fbcfdce
2018-10-26 18:18:41.377 27827-27827/genesis.com.getlocation V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=32 first=false flags=#81810100
2018-10-26 18:18:41.380 27827-27944/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:41.384 27827-27944/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:41.394 27827-27873/genesis.com.getlocation I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-27827-0](this:0xa8461000,id:0,api:1,p:27827,c:27827) queueBuffer: fps=0.67 dur=4486.29 max=3892.05 min=17.56
2018-10-26 18:18:41.403 27827-27945/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:41.405 27827-27945/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
```

I receive these logs afterwards always: (the difference is the Database is busy statement):

```
 2018-10-26 18:18:08.788 27080-27080/genesis.com.getlocation D/ConfirmDialogFragment: onDialogButtonClicked
2018-10-26 18:18:08.788 27080-27080/genesis.com.getlocation D/ConfirmDialogFragmentViewModel: RadioButton value is Desimus
2018-10-26 18:18:08.788 27080-27080/genesis.com.getlocation D/ConfirmDialogFragmentViewModel: Name of place is  Khan Plaza
2018-10-26 18:18:08.789 27080-27080/genesis.com.getlocation D/DatabaseController: Location Record Added Successfully
2018-10-26 18:18:08.791 27080-27775/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:08.805 27080-27775/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:08.824 27080-27166/genesis.com.getlocation D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x94b83e00,api=1)
2018-10-26 18:18:08.825 27080-27166/genesis.com.getlocation D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xa6043c40) (w:848 h:1264 s:848 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2018-10-26 18:18:08.826 27080-27166/genesis.com.getlocation D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xa60425c0) (w:848 h:1264 s:848 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2018-10-26 18:18:08.826 27080-27166/genesis.com.getlocation D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xa6042680) (w:848 h:1264 s:848 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2018-10-26 18:18:08.826 27080-27166/genesis.com.getlocation D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x94b83e00,api=1)
2018-10-26 18:18:08.829 27080-27602/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:08.831 27080-27602/genesis.com.getlocation D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
2018-10-26 18:18:08.859 27080-27080/genesis.com.getlocation D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: DecorView@3ad944e[], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@40be950
2018-10-26 18:18:08.867 27080-27080/genesis.com.getlocation V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=32 first=false flags=#81810100
2018-10-26 18:18:08.879 27080-27235/genesis.com.getlocation I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-27080-1](this:0xa8460000,id:1,api:1,p:27080,c:27080) queueBuffer: fps=0.44 dur=4554.45 max=4532.60 min=21.85
2018-10-26 18:18:08.893 27080-27235/genesis.com.getlocation I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-27080-1](this:0xa8460000,id:1,api:1,p:27080,c:27080) queueBuffer: slot 0 is dropped, handle=0xaaf91800
```

Comment: Why are you using `AsyncTask` for that ? Also where are you calling `addLocationRecord()` method? Where are you adding data to `LocationDetails` class?

Comment: Show full code.

Comment: A query should not be on main thread, it should run  on a separate thread as it could give delays to the UI, and im calling
    addLocationRecord() 
in my ViewModel. And LocationDetails is my entity class, ive added that in the code.

Comment: why are you using public void `setId()` eventhough you have set id to autogenerate? did you try to debug and check whether your call for insert is reachable or not.

Comment: Yes i've checked that as well. it is reachable .it runs . It displays the logs. Yet still no record

Comment: are you setting it up for the first time, looks like it wasn't setup properly.

Comment: @stallianz can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are not getting successful insert.

Make sure you are getting a primary ID back on insert 
Make sure you are doing the insert on a background thread.
Make sure you are doing the retrieve on a background thread

Also if you made changes to the model after installing that will cause it to fail at touching the DB because the schema no longer matches the model variables.

So check your database create line of code, and make sure you have a handle for schema changes such as changing your model. Destructive fallback is fine, or uninstall and resinstall if no one is using it yet.

Comment: Yes that is what i think too, Because everytime i insert a record the id in my logs during inserting is 0. ive reinstalled it too. have a migration code too but no changes in the scheme , But still , No record adds  in the database

Comment: Is there any way to confirm if my insert query is successful ?

Comment: Yes, by getting an ID in return. If you are not getting an ID, then there is something wrong with either your creation, your upgrade, or your insert statement. Check the logs, there is usually a good log showing what happened from Room

Comment: I just read this in the Logs. Can you tell me why this is so ?


2018-10-26 18:14:47.951 27080-27601/genesis.com.getlocation W/SQLiteConnection: Could not change the database journal as DB was busy. Proceeding...

Comment: Sounds like you have issues going on bigger than your insert. Do you initialize your database in your application file? Is the first time you touch it, when you are doing the insert or do you do it somewhere else before that and not handle properly. Are you certain that you are NOT on the ui thread interacting with it.

Comment: I initialize it in my Main activity right in onCreate(). This was working fine before. But before my Db instance was not singleton. and i created a new instance of my database class in each fragment where i needed them for any query. It was a new instance for each fragment. and i was also doing queries on the main thread before by adding .allowMainThreadQueries(). while building the database. But ever since i took this tutorial and changed all of that . im facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your LocationDetails class implements Serializable.
In your class extending RoomDatabase insert the class you want to add this way

```
 @Database(entities = {
        LocationDetails.class,
     },version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

and make sure to update the version number each time you add/remove a class in your database.
Also, I would recommend using the version 1.1.1-rc1 of room, which is more stable than 1.1.1 by adding this line in your gradle

```
 implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1-rc1'
```

Also, I would recommend calling your request in a Thread, on Android 6+ (maybe seven don't really recall) every AsyncTask of the devices share the same thread and wait there turn to execute the DoInBackground function and it can't take up to 5-10 sec sometimes to launch your task.

Comment: Tried that too.. still no solution

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for me was that I was copying just the database file (the one that usually has `.db` extension) and left out the `-shm` and `-wal` files.

When I copied those two files together with the main database file to my PC, and opened the main *.db* file, the tables and its records were shown successfully in my database viewer.

**Note:** SQLite database files are available in `/data/data/<the-app-package-name>/databases` on the device. Accessing them may require root privileges.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50987119/8583692) and its answers if you want to merge the files to the main database file.

For example, I created a separate DAO (Kotlin language) just for this:

```kotlin
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.RawQuery
import androidx.sqlite.db.SimpleSQLiteQuery
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteQuery

@Dao
abstract class DatabaseDao {

    open suspend fun flushDatabase() {
        checkpoint(SimpleSQLiteQuery("pragma wal_checkpoint(full)"))
    }

    @RawQuery
    protected abstract suspend fun checkpoint(supportSQLiteQuery: SupportSQLiteQuery): Int
}
```